# Program immediately closes when ran

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just finished writing my first Python program however as soon as i go to run it the window closes.  I tried a few fixes found in other threads with no luck.  Here is the code, is something in the syntax making it error out?  Thanks for the help!

```
print ('Lets do some math nerd!')
print ('How many problems would you like to solve?')
cycle = int(input())
rep = 0
while cycle < rep;
rep = rep + 1;

print ('What operation would you like to perform?')
print('Press 1 for Addition')
print('Press 2 for Subtraction')
print('Press 3 for Multiplication')
print('Press 4 for Division')

op = int(input())

if op ==1
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 + num2)
    print result

elif op ==2
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 - num2)
    print result

elif op ==3
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 * num2)
    print result

elif op ==4
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 / num2)
    print result

else    
    print ('ERROR')
    print (Please select a number 1 through 4.')
print ('Thanks for using my calculator!')

closeInput = raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
print "Closing..."
```

Comment: just run the code in the console instead of clicking on it. The window will not disappear, and you will be able to see the exception

Comment: This can not be right: `while cycle < rep;` . The first line of a `while` loop ends with `:`, and its body must be indented

Comment: How are you running it? If you are using a windows system, and If you are double clicking the python file, that is bound to happen. Instead, open the command prompt, and run `python myfile.py` instead

Comment: all of your calls to `input()` should be to `raw_input()` if you're using Python 2.7

Comment: You need `:` at the end of lines with `if`, `elif` and `else`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, looks like i have it working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your code.

I assume you are launching the program from a shortcut or launcher, which is why you would not see the error traceback python normally gives you.

Instead, run the program in a console. For example, `python myprogram.py` or `python3 myprogram.py`. This should give you a traceback for the error that kills the program.

The errors in your code:

- all if/ elseif/ else/ while lines should end with a colon
- the string on line 51 should have a starting quote
- everything under the while line (which should end with a colon) should be indented
- (not a syntax error) you should check for `rep < cycle`, not the other way arround

This is the fixed version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print ('Lets do some math nerd!')
print ('How many problems would you like to solve?')
cycle = int(input())
rep = 0
while rep < cycle:
    rep = rep + 1

    print ('What operation would you like to perform?')
    print('Press 1 for Addition')
    print('Press 2 for Subtraction')
    print('Press 3 for Multiplication')
    print('Press 4 for Division')

    op = int(input())

    if op ==1:
        print ('Enter your first number.')
        num1 = int(input())
        print ('Enter your second number.')
        num2 = int(input())
        result = (num1 + num2)
        print result

    elif op ==2:
        print ('Enter your first number.')
        num1 = int(input())
        print ('Enter your second number.')
        num2 = int(input())
        result = (num1 - num2)
        print result

    elif op ==3:
        print ('Enter your first number.')
        num1 = int(input())
        print ('Enter your second number.')
        num2 = int(input())
        result = (num1 * num2)
        print result

    elif op ==4:
        print ('Enter your first number.')
        num1 = int(input())
        print ('Enter your second number.')
        num2 = int(input())
        result = (num1 / num2)
        print result

    else:
        print ('ERROR')
        print ('Please select a number 1 through 4.')

print ('Thanks for using my calculator!')

closeInput = raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
print "Closing..."
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working now although i still cant get it to run from console, i think i need to do more troubleshooting with that.

Comment: What operating system are you using, and what is the command you use to run it? What does the console say when you enter the command?

Comment: I am on win 7, when i am on command line i can get python to run by typing C:\python27\python exe, however if i just type python it will not run giving me an error that it is not defined.

Comment: What happens when you run `C:\python27\python.exe myprogram.py` (where myprogram.py is your program)? You can get the `python` command by [adding python to your path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Comment: I will look into that link a bit later when i have some more time.  Thank you for your help Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "import pdb" in the 1st line, then run and it will help you debug your programme.

Several grammar error:
1. Line 7, while loop use ":" instead of ";"
2. Line 8, IndentationError: expected an indented block
3. Line 18, if op ==1:  , and same for all your if statement.
4. Line 52, print ('Please

Done.

```
import pdb

print ('Lets do some math nerd!')
print ('How many problems would you like to solve?')
cycle = int(input())
rep = 0
while cycle < rep:
        rep = rep + 1

print ('What operation would you like to perform?')
print('Press 1 for Addition')
print('Press 2 for Subtraction')
print('Press 3 for Multiplication')
print('Press 4 for Division')

op = int(input())

if op ==1:
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 + num2)
    print result

elif op ==2:
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 - num2)
    print result

elif op ==3:
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 * num2)
    print result

elif op ==4:
    print ('Enter your first number.')
    num1 = int(input())
    print ('Enter your second number.')
    num2 = int(input())
    result = (num1 / num2)
    print result

else:
    print ('ERROR')
    print ('Please select a number 1 through 4.')
print ('Thanks for using my calculator!')

closeInput = raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
print "Closing..."
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, looks like i had more problems than i was first aware of however it is now working!