# No module named _multiprocessing / requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been looking exhaustively at the different error messages to try and resolve this, and I have run a number of reinstalls of both python 2.7 and ipython, but I just cannot get ipython notebook to launch.

The `catch_config_error` in `application.py` would suggest an incorrect 'trait' setup, which is beyond my area of knowledge

I am also very confused by the  `"IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11"` as `pip list` is showing version ~14

i have a feeling I might have some PATH variables incorrectly setup, and there is a folder 
csvn with a python25 folder in it?

See error messages and pip log below

`Iptest` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
 exec code in run_globals
File "C:\csvn\Python25\Scripts\iptest.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\testing\iptestcontroller.py",
line 23, in <module>
import multiprocessing.pool
 File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
import _multiprocessing
ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing
```

`Pip list` returns:

```
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
certifi (14.05.14)
distribute (0.6.49)
docutils (0.12)
eventlet (0.14.0)
greenlet (0.4.2)
ipython (2.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
nose (1.3.3)
numpydoc (0.5)
pip (1.5.6)
Pygments (1.6)
pyreadline (2.0)
pyzmq (14.3.1)
setuptools (0.6c11)
Sphinx (1.2.2)
tornado (4.0)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

and

`Ipython Notebook` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in st
art_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
563, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321,
 in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 38
1, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316,
 in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
475, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
406, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line
42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 39
, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 37
, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like your default python interpreter in your path is not the one you just installed, But some former version you installed to "C:\csvn\Python25". Pip installs the packages for your 2.7 Python interpreter, but of course they are not seen in your Python25 installation. You don't really ask a specific question, so it's hard to post an answer.

Comment: I would like to know how to repair the path.and launch Ipython notebook Should there be a python27 in my csvn folder?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, so I probably should not try to give you advice here. Setting up python on windows does not seem to be straight forward. But if you search stackoverflow, you will find guides for many common problems:
How to edit the PATH variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7
How to install pip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
it turns out I had an old copy of python 2.5 installed on my C:\ CSVN.

I delete it,

Uninstalled all other version of python using an uninstall tool

i then install Anaconda and now everything works fine.

While the Python25 folder was probably was the main issue, I would recommend using a valid uninstall tool, as the one in the windows control panel might not meet requirements.

Comment: This is not a Windows-specific problem. I'm getting the same error on Mac.