# py launcher does not find my Python 2.7

Tags: python, installation

I'm on Windows 7. I have Python 2.7 installed for years. I installed recently Python 3.4. I'm trying to use the new py launcher. When I open the cmd terminal and type `py -2`, I get this error message: `Requested Python version (2) not installed`. How can make py aware of my python 2.7 installation?

Note: python 2.7 is installed in a non-standard directory (not in C:\Python27), in case this is the problem.

Comment: I tried installing 2.7.8 in a nonstandard directory (literally `C:\Python_non_standard_directory`) and made sure the `Add python.exe to Path` option was unchecked. The result of that install was that `py -2` still worked as expected, as did `py -3`. Unfortunately, I don't have any recommendations, but I thought that my test might help put you on the right track.

Comment: Just to clarify: did you install python 2.7.8 after installing python 3?

Comment: I had Python 3.4.1 installed to begin with before installing 2.7.8.

Comment: if python3 was installed first then just uninstall the pylauncher and modify python3 in controlpanel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution. The registry had wrong entries. As I have a 32 bit version installed I went to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE|HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath` and the value was set to `C:\Python27` while my installation is in `D:\Python27`. So I changed all the registry values to match the correct location and it now works fine.

It's been quite a while I installed Python 2.7, but I assume I had Python 2.7 installed first. Then I deleted it and installed pythonxy in this new location. I probably didn't uninstall the previous version correctly.

Comment: This also works to get py.exe to run an anaconda version of python. Just add the appropriate key and point it to the anaconda path.

Comment: There are actually _three locations_ in the registry, and the `py launcher` picks from HKCU according to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/#structure

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with Py Launcher failing to recognize my Python 2.7 install. I found editing the Windows Registry (Windows 10) by adding `2.7` to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7]`
solved my problem.

Other Window versions may have the `PythonCore` key in a different location.

Here is the full export of the tree I added:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
"ExecutablePath"="C:\\Users\\kcec11\\Python\\Python27\\python.exe"
"WindowedExecutablePath"="C:\\Users\\kcec11\\Python\\Python27\\pythonw.exe"
@="C:\\Users\\kcec11\\Python\\Python27\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of problem in Windows occurs because Python isn't in the OS path defined as an environment variable.

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7), try going to the "Advanced System Settings", edit "Environment Variables" and include `;C:\python27` (in your case, the place where you installed Python 2.7) to the path.

Comment: My python path is D:\Python27. If I run from the terminal `echo %PATH%` I can find `D:\Python27`. Also I can run python 2 from the terminal by typing `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, another answer - trying out my codebase which I've been using with 3.8.3 for quite a while and I was wanting to test with 3.9.1 because I've experienced getting too far behind the version number curve before to want to experience it again, so using a clean env with just 3.9.1 installed, trying to run from source it gave this error:

```
Requested Python version (3.8) is not installed
```

After fifteen minutes of head scratching and searching without any result, and I already can't remember why I checked this but it turns out I had a shebang in line 1 of my main .py file (I'm on Windows):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

change this to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

and now it works with Python 3.9.1 :-)

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html