# How can I add a Python version to the Python Launcher?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-2.x

On Windows, how can I add a Python version to the Python Launcher? I have python 3.7 installed alongside 2.7. I've made sure that the `PATH` variable and the registry keys are correct. One thing I will say is that I can't see any other Python environment variables on my machine (such as `PYTHONPATH`), or either of the `py.ini` files descibed [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/#configuration-file).

If possible, I would like the solution to also work with python distribition, such as Anaconda.

This is the same question as [py launcher does not find my Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503003/py-launcher-does-not-find-my-python-2-7), but none of the answers worked for me, so I trust I am allowed to ask again.

related:
[How should I set the default Python version in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-the-default-python-version-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to `Control Panel -> Uninstall A Program`, right clicking on "Python 2.7.15", clicking "change", and pressing "repair". No clue why I didn't try that first.