# How does the Windows Python Launcher (py.exe) find the python executable(s)?

Tags: python, windows, launcher

I'm trying to use the Windows Python Launcher (py.exe) for the first time.  I run python in a command shell but the launcher, running in the same shell, can't find any version of python.exe to run:

```
where python                                          
C:\Python38\python.exe                                  
py --list                                             
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows      
No Installed Pythons Found!
```

Obviously there is something missing in my configuration but I'm at a loss as to what.  I've been digging into the registery and have located keys in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Python/PyLauncher   
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Python/PythonCore
```

but there isn't anything that references any executables.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: At first I was going to write a pithy comment telling you to read the documentation and how to find it. But then I realized that the information there is actually not very useful for your specific question. Even so, this question seems like a better fit for https://superuser.com (I couldn't find a duplicate there, either). On my own machine, the behaviour is the reverse: `py` finds my Python installations that are not on the PATH, but `where python` comes up empty-handed and `python` only works inside a venv.

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right path. In your case, you would need to add the following entries in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath]
@="C:\\python38\\"
"ExecutablePath"="C:\\Python38\\python.exe"
"WindowedExecutablePath"="C:\\Python38\\pythonw.exe"
```

Also answered in [py launcher does not find my Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503003/py-launcher-does-not-find-my-python-2-7)