# How can I run PHPUnit from git bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, phpunit, git-bash

I have Windows 7, phpunit is installed via these instructions: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html and works fine from regular `cmd` terminal, but `phpunit` is not recognized in the windows git bash terminal installed from git-scm.

I'm mainly a linux developer, so setting this stuff up on Windows is a little foreign to me.

Comment: Sounds like your need to add a path to your environment. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7 for a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias native will be much better. edit ~/.bashrc, add these in it:

```
alias phpunit="php /C/Tools/php/phpunit.phar" // phpunit.phar in C:\Tools\php\phpunit.phar
```

Answer (score 1):

copy the phpunit.phar file and rename the dumplicate file to phpunit

> rename C:\bin\phpunit.phar to C:\bin\phpunit

[Fix: PHPUnit not working with Git Bash in Windows](https://south634.com/fix-phpunit-not-working-with-git-bash-in-windows/)

Comment: Please provide some context for the link. For more information, see ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same problem myself, see this answer provided at SuperUser https://superuser.com/a/663187, basically the problem is that Git Bash does not run ".bat" files: