# Install AskBot from live onto local machine

Tags: python, github, askbot

I'm trying to install a live version of an askbot build on my local machine (windows 7)

I have a .tar of the codebase downloaded, but now have no idea how to install it, or even where to install it.

Looking at this http://askbot.org/doc/install.html suggests that I would get a fresh install, would I then be able to import into that?

The developer who made the live version has left the company.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have given is not enough to help you. You seem to imply you already have some form of askbot installed, but not locally?
Either way you would need a version of python installed. Hold your windows key and press r, or otherwise open the run dialog from your machine. In the dialog box type 'cmd', without the quotes. A terminal window should pop up. Here type 'python'. If a Python version, Date and someother text appear, followed by '>>>' you have python installed. If not, its a good place to start downloading and installing it, its very straightforward. Go to [Python.Org](https://www.python.org/)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Someone who used to work here installed askbot on one of our servers. I downloaded that codebase and now want to run it locally on my machine, but don't know how to do that. 

I typed "python" into the cmd line but nothing came up, so I downloaded it and typed python again and still nothing (even though I can see it is installed)

Comment: That is strange, can you post a screenshot of your terminal after you typed python? You want to run it locally to access the data, or to host it as it was before?

Comment: Here you go http://imgur.com/JV6RghO I want to run it locally to access and edit the data, and then also deploy it locally so I can see those changes in action before pushing it live. Thanks for your help BTW!

Comment: You need to add python.exe to PATH. Another thread explains this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7. From there you need to check if pip came with your python package, and that it too is included in PATH. you do this by simply typing 'pip' in the terminal as you did with 'python'. If that reports no error and instead gives usage options, you can now follow the instructions detailed by Askbot, The difference will be when you come to configuring your database, which seems like it would be in your 'tar' file. If you have problems then, come back.