# PowerShell fails to recognize Python

Tags: python, powershell

Trying to learn Python using an educational book entitled, "Learn Python The Hard Way" and I am having a difficult time getting PowerShell to recognize Python. I installed Notepad ++ and started PowerShell...no problem. I was told that sometimes Windows doesn't configure Path correctly and was instructed to enter

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","$env:Path;C:\Python27","User")
```

I entered the line above but Python isn't recognized even after a re-start. Any suggestions? I am a programming novice so please be as clear as possible with your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to be navigated to the right directory. Try:

```
   cd ..
   C:\Python27\
```

Comment: Thank you but could you be a little bit more specific. I am completely new to programming. Where should I enter cd..  or cd\Correct\Directory I know Pyrhon resides in C:\Python27\

Comment: Thank you very much..this is the first chance I got all week to try to solve my problem. Someone else on Stack told me to type Machine instead of User at the end of the command and it worked. I sure yours would also have done the trick. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you have worked fine for me. You could try possibly changing "User" to "Machine" and it would set that variable for the whole machine not just a user. Once executed, close your PowerShell windows and reopen and check again.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that tonight and let you know ASAP if it worked.