# What would cause "python.exe" to work while "python" fails in Windows command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, environment-variables

I am using Python 2.7.2 on a Windows 7 machine, and I have been setting the `PATH` variable in the command prompt each time that I want access to Python. Today, I noticed that the behavior changes if I append the directory to the front of the back of the `PATH` variable.

On opening a command prompt, it recognizes neither `python` or `python.exe`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\z1083743>python
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\z1083743>python.exe
'python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I add the python binary directory onto the back of the path, it recognizes one but not the other:

```
C:\Users\z1083743>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\FUEL\std-1.4.10.1\Windows-x64-vs10.0\python-2.7.2\bin

C:\Users\z1083743>python
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\z1083743>python.exe
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z
```

If I add the Python binary directory on the front of the path, it recognizes both:

```
C:\Users\z1083743>set PATH=C:\FUEL\std-1.4.10.1\Windows-x64-vs10.0\python-2.7.2\bin;%PATH%

C:\Users\z1083743>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z


C:\Users\z1083743>python.exe
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z
```

I've read through all of the answers to the [adding-python-path-on-windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) question, but all of them are aimed at just getting it working. As far as I can tell, none of them would describe the behavior that I'm seeing.

What's happening here? Why does it need the `.exe` extension in one case and not the other?

Comment: There's some other `python` in another `PATH` directory with an extension that's in `PATHEXT`, but not .exe. Check `where python`.

Comment: That was it! There was a `python.cmd` in one of the other directories that pointed to a (non-existent) `python.exe` path.

Comment: Now for meta: why comment instead of answer? What do I do once someone has satisfactorily answered the question?