# How to add .py script to run on another py (python)

Tags: python

I have a python (.py) script. I want to add a code to run guideType.py on gui.py script. When I opening the program it runs gui.py. So I want to be  executing that guideType.py when it  starts

gui.py = http://d-h.st/UsZY

guideType.py = http://d-h.st/7SNF

Comment: Just include the script you want to run inside the second script

Comment: I'm no any good at python... :( please can u help me

Comment: Exactly what Anand S Kumar just said

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "execute". You either import that file as a module and call the functions you need (that's preferable), or use [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile).

Comment: What actully wanna add
<setting id="xmltv.type_select" label="30123" type="action" action="RunScript($CWD/guideTypes.py)"/> this is doing by xml. I want it to do in pythongfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import os, sys

path_python_exec = sys.executable
path_exec_file = ''

command = '%s %s'%(path_python_exec, path_exec_file)
os.system(command)
```

Customize it according to your needs.

Comment: This runs the something. But not python. Shows CMD and no any execute of. This is the settings.xml. Please check. There have execute. it wanna done in that
http://d-h.st/40N9

Comment: @NishanthaIndikaBandara please post your code here (in your original post), not onto some external site.

Comment: Code is little bit long

Comment: <setting id="xmltv.type_select" label="30123" type="action" action="RunScript($CWD/guideTypes.py)"/> 
this is doing by xml. I want it to do in pythong file

Comment: From what I understand from the xml is path to execute  is 'Current Directory + guideTypes.py'. So keep path_exec_file = os.getcwd() + '\\guideTypes.py'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `import` of the script, that would cause the statements in that script get executed.

```
import gui
```

Comment: <setting id="xmltv.type_select" label="30123" type="action" action="RunScript($CWD/guideTypes.py)"/> this is doing by xml. I want it to do in python file

Comment: Like I said, if you want to run the script, just `import` it in your other script, if both pythons are in the same folder. If not , you can import using absolute path using - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: Yes on same path. I added that. Then what wanna add to gui.py file?

Comment: you dont need to add anything else, this should work

Comment: Nothing at all? Can you do one thing, put a `print("Something")` as first line of your gui.py script and check if that is getting printed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.system("python guideType.py")` when you want to execute the second python script. Otherwise, `subprocess` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) might help you achieve what you are asking.

Comment: This also runs. But showing cmd as python is not recognized command

Comment: Have you added python to your path (if you are using Windows)? You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) if you are using Python 2.7 to get help adding python to system path.

Comment: <setting id="xmltv.type_select" label="30123" type="action" action="RunScript($CWD/guideTypes.py)"/> this is doing by xml. I want it to do in pythong file