# How do i play a sound in python 3?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I wanted to write a python script to play a sound (recorded using windows recorder)!

I read pygame can do the job and installed pygame! But I don't know how to write a code that plays a sound from a specific path! I have to play an audio file located at `C:\Users\Asdf\Documents\Audio.wav`

I tried a script from here http://pythonprogramming.net/adding-sounds-music-pygame/

```
import pygame
crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.wav")
```

But then I get an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.wav") AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mixer'

So how do I write the script to play that Audio.wav file using pygame?

I am using Python 3.4 64 bit version!

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound

Comment: http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.mixer.Sound.play

Comment: 1. Do you have the right pygame version installed? (python 3 64bit) 2. Do you use a filename other than `pygame.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Add python to windows 7 PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

1. Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. In "User variables" Click "New" if there is no PATH, else select PATH variable and click "Edit"
5. Append `;C:\python34` to the `Path` variable.
6. Restart Command Prompt.

[image]

### Installing pygame

You first want to install pygame. You can do this in a number of ways.
But to install from source

1. Download and extract [pygame-1.9.1release.zip](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.zip)
2. Open a terminal
3. cd into the *pygame-1.9.1release* folder you just extracted
4. Run `python setup.py`

Alternatively if python is associated with `.py` files in your windows installation (this is the default), open the extracted folder and double click `setup.py`

### Running pygame

You need to run

```
pygame.init()
```

Before any calls to pygame modules !

Hope that solves the problem for you

**Example**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\\Users\\Asdf\\Documents\\Audio.wav")

# Start playback
s.play()

# Stop playback
s.stop()
```

### Play a sound on windows (without pygame)

```
import winsound

fname = "C:\\Users\\Asdf\\Documents\\Audio.wav"
winsound.PlaySound(fname, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: This code seems the same as mine except mine does not work. Im trying on a Raspberry pi though and not windows. I keep getting an error message my_sound = pygame.mixer.my_sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav') AttributeError: module 'pygame.mixer' has no attribute 'my_sound'

Is there something wrong in the code or my setup?

Thanks
import pygame

pygame.init

my_sound= pygame.mixer.sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav')

my_sound.play()

Answer (score 4):

I've used [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) effectively for this purpose. The module can be installed as

`pip install pydub`

[pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) does need [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed. Details of installation of pydub and ffmpeg given @ https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub

Once the above dependancies are installed, The library provides comprehensive manipulation of various audio formats across different platforms [ windows , Linux , Mac ] in rather easy way.

Here is an example

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

fname = "C:\\Users\\Asdf\\Documents\\Audio.wav"
mysong = AudioSegment.from_wav(fname)
play(mysong)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple solution that works on all platforms with no dependencies other than a single Python file.

First install `playsound` with pip:

```
pip install playsound
```

Then import the function of the same name from the module and run it. Pretty easy, no?

```
from playsound import playsound
# wav works on all platforms. mp3 works on OS X. Other filetype/OS combos may work but have not been tested.
playsound('/path/to/file/you/want/to/play.wav')
```

Disclaimer: I wrote `playsound`. It takes an optional second argument, `block = False`, which will make it so the function call doesn't block. It'll block by default.

Comment: looks like playsound doesn't work on Linux at the moment:

https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/1

Comment: Playsound doesn't run with Python3, also has some dependencies not included in the package.

Comment: It works great for me using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.