# Ambiguity on Python Installation

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

So I am new to Python and installed it using guidelines from various websites, as I want to try basic examples before moving on the advanced python concepts. Below is my understanding and installation tasks that I performed.

1) Installed **Python 2.7** form the website.

2) Installed **Anaconda** as I read that it has pre installed libraries.

3) Downloaded pip file and ran it on the Python interpreter and it was done successfully, but when I try using **pip install ipython** , it throws an error saying **pip** is not defined.

4)Now I downloaded **Pycharm** as a IDE, done successfully.

5) Programs run perfectly, but I see many instances of Ipthon on every related website and I am not able to understand if I need it. Ipython is used for web I guess but I really don't understand how to integrate everything. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you using and what is the exact error that you're getting? did you try to google it? ;)

Comment: 1) 2) and 3) should be roughly mutually exclusive. 2) is best IMHO, Ananconda comme with Python, and PIP. Also Please we are in 2015, use Python3.

Comment: @Matt "There are a few minor downsides, such as slightly worse library support" is a statement on Python 3 on the Python website, so I installed 2.7.

Comment: @alfasin I am using windows 8 64-bit . Can you put some light on whether I need Ipython and how can I install it? . Is it done through command prompt or Windows power-shell or Python interpreter or Anaconda interpreter?

Comment: As @Matt says: if you want to use IPython, just install Anaconda. That will include Python, pip and IPython, there should be no need to install any of them separately.

Comment: @Meesha Where did you read this statement about "worse library support" personally I use library that don't exist on Python2

Comment: @Matt https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows,  pip error is probably related to environmental variables not being set.

See this answer for details on pip
[Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

---

### response to comment

Ipython is not necessary, but it will make life easier.  I use command prompt and am not familiar with installing packages with Pycharm or anaconda.

If Pip is installed, and the Windows environmental variable is not set, you can still use pip.

1) open a windows command prompt as administrator 
2) navigate to your python installation ( default Directory is C:\Python27 )
3) navigate to scripts folder (default dir C:\Python27\Scripts)
4) type 'pip'

5) type 'pip freeze' to see packages installed with pip.  Note: pip does not keep track of packages installed with conda

If you were able to complete those steps, changing the PATH variable to include the scripts directory will allow you to run pip by simply typing 'pip' from anywhere.

To install Ipython:
From command prompt with administrator rights:
'pip install ipython[all]'

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at it and definitely sort it out. Can you put some light on whether I need Ipython and how can I install it? . Is it done through command prompt or Windows power-shell or Python interpreter or Anaconda interpreter?

Comment: You don't "need" IPython. Like you don't "need" a IDE to program in C++. It's a choice you if you want a nice REPL. Some alternative are bPython, ptpython,...

Comment: Also, many tools like Ipython/pycharm do not require special knowledge to get started with, but they have learning curves and if the goal is to learn python, the tools may take you on a tangent.