# Windows missing Python.h

Tags: python, windows, theano

I'm trying to run a sample Theano code that uses GPU on windows.
My python (with python-dev and Theano and all required libraries) was installed from Anaconda.
This is the error I run into:

`Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory`

My `Python.h` is actually in `c://Anaconda/include/`

I'm guessing that I should add that directory to some environmental variable, but I don't know which.

Comment: Did you do this with the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Comment: you have to istall python headers aka python-dev

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Visual Studio in Windows, right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and navigate as follows: Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> Add C:/Anaconda/include/ (or wherever your Anaconda install is located)