# Python is not recognized in cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

I am trying to confirm that I've succesfuly downloaded Python, yet after the installation was finished (everything seems okay, all files, etc., are there), my cmd doesn't recognize it, and returns a message saying that Python is not recognized as batch file, operable program and so on.

Why does this happen? I write `python` in the cmd as my Python Tutorial book says. I am also trying to run Python 2.7.

Comment: Assuming you are on windows, can you do this: `echo %PATH%` please and add the output to your question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8yy8uy , Before validating that Python is in my enviroment path, yet the same output appears after i wrote "set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib " in my cmd.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` really has nothing to do with this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix:
Check 'Add python.exe to path' while installing it. 
[Here's where this option is.](http://tinypic.com/r/2l93x2h/9)

Answer (score 1):

During installation (In the last step) there is a radio button asking if you want to add python into a system path so that you can access it from cmd. Check that button and everything will be fine. Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)