# XLSX Parser not installing on Node JS

Tags: node.js, excel, express, npm, npm-install

I'm getting following error while installing [Simple NodeJS XLSX parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel)

```
D:\www\MeanProject\providerapp>npm install excel
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possibl
e.

> libxmljs@0.14.3 install D:\www\MeanProject\providerapp\node_modules\excel\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild

|
D:\www\MeanProject\providerapp\node_modules\excel\node_modules\libxmljs>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\n
ode-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\www\MeanProject\providerapp\node_modules\excel\node_modules\libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "excel"
npm ERR! node v4.2.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.14.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.14.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\www\MeanProject\providerapp\npm-debug.log
```

I've installed `script 'node-gyp rebuild'` & Python as shown in the above error but still error persist.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error is explicit: **Can't find Python executable "python"**. You need to install python or add it to your PATH.

Comment: @ShanShan: I installed it but still problem persist

Comment: Can you try `python` in command line, if it says *command not found*, python is not in the PATH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7#6318188