# error in creating http server on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, http, server

I want to set up Python SimpleHTTPServer on windows XP. I have Python installed on my computer. I am executing the following command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

But I am getting the error:

> python : 
>   The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You may need to add Python to your Windows PATH environment variable. Does it work if you run the same command from the directory that contains python.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Python is not in your PATH enviroment variable. To fix this try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/6400392

> 1. Hold Win and press Pause.
> 2. Click Advanced System Settings.
> 3. Click Environment Variables.
> 4. Append ;C:\python27 to the Path variable.
> 5. Restart Command Prompt.