# How to install Openpyxl with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openpyxl

I have windows 10 (64 bit). I want to utilize the `Openpyxl` package to start learning how to interact with excel and other spreadsheets.

I installed Python with `"windowsx86-64web-basedinstaller"` I have a 64 bit OS, was I mistaken when trying to install this version?

[image: Python Details in Command Prompt]
[image: Python Installation Options]
[image: I found some pip.exes in the script folder of python]

Comment: Have tried `pip install openpyxl`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to ensure that `C:\Python35\Scripts` is in your system path. Follow the top answer instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) to do that:

You run the command in windows command prompt, not in the python interpreter that you have open.

Press:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Type `CMD` in the run window which has opened

Type `pip install openpyxl` in windows command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do: `c:\Users\xxxx>c:/python27/scripts/pip install openpyxl`
I had to save the openpyxl files in the scripts folder.

Answer (score 2):

**(optional) Install git for windows** (https://git-scm.com/) to get git bash. Git bash is much more similar to Linux terminal than Windows cmd.

**Install Anaconda 3**

```
https://www.anaconda.com/download/
```

It should set itself into Windows PATH. Restart your PC. Then pip should work in your cmd

**Then in cmd (or git bash), run command**

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 0):

1. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl
   download zip file and unzip it on local system.
2. go to openpyxl folder where setup.py is present.
3. open command prompt under the same path.
4. Run a command: python setup.py install
5. It will install openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#files
2. Download the file and
   unzip in your pc in the main folder, there's a file call setup.py
3. Install with this command: python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

1. go to command prompt, and run as Administrator
2. in c:/> prompt -> pip install openpyxl
3. once you run in CMD you will get message like,
   Successfully installed et-xmlfile-1.0.1 jdcal-1.4.1 openpyxl-3.0.5
4. go to python interactive shell and run openpyxl module
5. openpyxl  will work