# Python running from command line - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run my program from the command line, it errors stating that it can't find openpyxl, with the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'openpyxl'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

-Thanks

EDIT: Using Python 3.6, I can run it fine from PyCharm, but when I can't run it from the cmd line.

Comment: do you have different python versions installed on your machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Openpyxl with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364404/how-to-install-openpyxl-with-pip)

Comment: @Cut7er nope - just Python 3.6

Comment: you havn't share much, so alot can go wrong.... wrong python version? wrong virtual environment? problem with relative import? can't tell with this little details

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509198/no-module-named-openpyxl-python-3-4-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply install `openpyxl` to your own computer by opening Command Prompt or Terminal, and typing:

```
pip install openpyxl # For Python 2
pip3 install openpyxl # For Python 3
```

Comment: This probably should have been a comment. There's tonnes of similar questions that could be used as a dupe; presumably they're installing to a different version of python than they get from the command line

Comment: Almost the right answer, but you made an honest attempt to answer the question so marked it correct for anyone that may have a similar issue in the future. The actual syntax I needed was `py -m pip install openpyxl`. (This is for windows 10) Thanks!