# How can I get virtualenv to work?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have this weird error:

```
Path:\To\My\Command>virtualenv .
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
    '"D:\Python27\python.exe"  "F:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe" .'
```

Thing is, I don't have a `D:\Python27\python.exe`. My `D:` drive became my `F:` drive when I got my new computer and there's no `D:\Python27` listed in my environment variables. Is there someplace else I should be looking?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Try reinstalling Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your environmental variable path is messed up. Try setting it up again for F:\, you can find directions here: [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)