# system cannot find the path specified in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 on windows. I am getting "Calling function "tests/scripts/Script.py"... The system cannot find the path specified when the tests are executed.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add python Lib and Scrip path to your system environment. To do that type > Edit the system environment variables in search box of start menu. go to edit variable and add python required path to system path.