# running python from external HDD

Tags: python, windows

My question follows the explanation.

I have managed to run python from an external HDD.  Its not fast but it is usable while traveling.  What I did was download Anaconda onto my HDD and then installed it on the HDD giving the program its own path.  Now I have access to python, numpy, scipy, sympy, etc. on whatever machine I am on.  In order for me to run python I use CMD from the windows machine and change my directory to the python install directory.  To explain this further I installed python on 'E:\Anaconda3' and to run python I open CMD and then type 'E:' to change to my HDD followed by 'cd \Anaconda3' then I type 'python' and I now have python in my CMD.  To run scripts I have on my HDD I do the same thing but instead of typing 'python' to initiate a python window I type 'python E:\scripts\test.py' and I can run my scripts.

My question is: is there an easier way to do this????

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Comment: The `/d` switch to cd is useful for switching drive and directory: `cd /d e:\anaconda3`. `virtualenv` might be helpful depending on what you want to accomplish (or the windows version of `virtualenv-wrapper`)