# Why can't Python run in Atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I've researched this on different places, including stackoverflow, and I can't find an answer that helps me.

I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit, with Atom for 64 bit Windows. I have Python 3.6.1 installed in the directory C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Python. When I try to run a simple script to test Python in Atom, it says

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   [Finished in 0.083s]

I tried to run the same script in the command line, and it said the same thing. I'm new to programming, so please try to be a little patient.

Comment: You need to add the Python executable to your environmental variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is probably that your Python command is not listed in your `PATH` environment variable.

**Environment Variables** are paths, values and other information stored by your operating system and used globally by the OS and different applications you use.

The best example for a command listed in the `PATH` environment variable is `cmd` or `ping`. try to tap  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`, note how it opens a new Command Line even though you don't really know where `cmd.exe` is stored on your hard drive? That is because the path `C:\Windows\System32` is stored in your `PATH` variable.

So, we know you installed python, but you want to be able to run it without specifying it's path, how can we do that? Simply add it to our environment variables:

1. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>
2. Click on `Advanced system settings`
3. At the bottom of the window click on `Environment Variables...`
4. In the `System Variables` section find the `PATH` variable
5. Double click it
6. A new window with a text box has opened, go to it's end with the <kbd>end</kbd> button
7. Paste the path `C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Python` at it's end (be sure to add a `;` before pasting if there isn't one there.
8. Click ok
9. Open a new `cmd` window
10. Try and type `python` you should be all set now, on the command line and in Atom.

If it isn't clear, the <kbd>win</kbd> button is the button on your keyboard with the windows icon on it.

Comment: It still gives me the same error. This is the new directory under my PATH variable - C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Python

Comment: Try to open a new `cmd` and go to the path `C:\U‌​sers\Austin\Document‌​s\Python`, then try typing `./python` does that work?

Comment: Even with C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Python it still gives me the error that  it isn't recongnized.

Comment: Did typing `./python` work when you went straight to it's path on `cmd`? If not, there might be something wrong with your python installation...

Comment: Yes. I tried C:\U‌​sers\Austin\Document‌​s\Python and ./python, and both give me the error. Let me reinstall Python...

Comment: OK, do note that while installing python it offers you to add it to the `PATH` automatically, it's easiest if you tell it to do that, saves you the manual work

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: Solved! I didn't see that option to add to PATH. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, if the answer helped you be sure to mark it as the correct one for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with same problem: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
I solved it using following way:

1. In search bar type python, your latest installed python 32-bit app would appear. Select it and right click.
2. Then select open file location
   [image]
3. A new page would pop up with auto selected python 32-bit file. Now right click and again select open file location.

[image]

4. Copy the path as I have selected in picture.
   [image]
5. Now in search bar type Advanced System Setting, and click on it.
   [image]
6. A new window will pop up. Click on environment variables.

[image]

7. First select Path then Click on edit.
   [image]
8. Now A new window of edit variable path will open up. In this first click on new >> Add the path of python 32-bit app that we copied  >> click on ok.

[image]

9. Now Click OK on environment variables window, Next click OK on system variables window as well.
   [image]

[image]

10. Now python is ready to run in Atom

Answer (score 1):

Adding python to my path, (installed as C:\Program Files\Python39\Python.exe) worked, but only after restarting Atom. Make sure you do that. Looks like it doesn't dynamically watch and reload the path variable from the system ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In very direct terms, it means that there is no executable file named **python.exe** in any dictionary in your search path (which I think is the PATH environment variable on Windows).

First of all, try executing python from the installation directory.  If that works, you *know* that you have it installed properly, and that the problem is the search path.  If that fails, try again with the full path name, such as `C:\Users\Austin\Documents\Python\python.exe`.

Does that move you closer to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the latest Python version. One of the first installation screens has a toggle box at the bottom that you can click to add the directory to Path. This worked for me when I ran into the same problem. You have to manually click though and it's easy to ignore it.

Comment: this has worked for me because when I reinstalled python from scratch and check that checkbox, actually it has added more than one path to environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, by put the good python path in Atom ide-Python
simply i put D:\my_python_folder\Python.exe

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. What did work, is installing Python from the Microsoft Store instead of downloading from the web and installing from an installer.