# Installing Python + ATOM Editor (Error - Python is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or bath file)

Tags: python, atom-editor

I want to freshly install Python (latest version is 3.8.0). And later on I plan to install ATOM editor to execute python program and then SCRIPT package in ATOM to execute python script.

Can someone guide me, in which path (of Windown OS) should I install Python and ATOM; so that I don't get the following error and any other configuration/settings changes required? Also, please help me in explaining the basics (if time permits) i.e. why we're doing such installation, etc.

**Error -** "Python is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or bath file".

(Since I'm a completely new to programming in Python, I couldn't clealy understand why I got this error. Hence I uninstalled everything and want to redo everything from the beginning and also understand WHY we're doing this way)

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

Thanks Shijith for [sharing the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669897/why-cant-python-run-in-atom).

I'm now able to run python code through ATOM editor. Here's what I did:

Freshly installed Python on Windows. Copy the folder path where Python is installed (in my case C:\Users\Python), go to Environment Variable, select "Path" in system variable, click Edit, the existing value was "%SystemRoot%\system32" (without double quotes). In the end of this value, I entered semicolon and folder path where Python was installed. So the final value becomes (without double quotes) "%SystemRoot%\system32;C:\Users\Python".

That's it. Now click OK, OK, OK.

Now install ATOM, install package "SCRIPT" and try any small code to check whether all works fine. So e.g. I tried print("hi"). ATOM will now execute the script correctly, i.e. the output was "hi".

Basically all this happened because "Python path is not in system variable". That is why we entered Python path in the environment variable called "Path".

Hope this will help others.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error and command you used?

Comment: Hi, Since I could not find the solution correctly, I'd uninstalled Python and ATOM. Initially (after installing Python & ATOM) I ran a very simple script print("hello world") to check whether program runs correctly or not. But it gave error "Python is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file".

Comment: refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669897/why-cant-python-run-in-atom

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)