# No module named 'scipy'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, scipy, pycharm

I am writing my first machine learning program. I am totally new i am writing the python code in pycharm but i am getting error as below.
i can't even find any tutorial for beginners maybe most people don't know it

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

```
from sklearn import  tree
features = [[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features,labels)
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/LENOVO/PycharmProjects/MyPython/MyPyton.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from sklearn import  tree   File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py",
>   line 134, in 
>       from .base import clone   File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from scipy import sparse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Comment: if you have installed pip, then pip install scipy, cause sklearn depend on scipy

Comment: so what should i have to do now?

Comment: Use it: https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: it is not for the windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option: Presumably you downloaded Python from python.org (i.e. you searched the web for "download Python" and clicked on the first link, which is fair enough). Instead, I suggest downloading and using the [Anaconda Python distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/), which comes with a scipy (and many other useful packages) precompiled for Windows.

Edit: A month after posting this answer, [scipy 1.0 was released](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.1.0.0.html) and one of the features was pre-built binary wheels for Windows. In plain language, this means you can now run `pip install scipy` on Windows and it will just work. However, there are still plenty of Python packages that need building but do not have pre-built wheels for Windows, so overall it is still sensible to use Anaconda (or similar) to install Python and packages.

Comment: yes i downloaded the anaconda but how to use that with pycharm my problem is still the same

Answer (score 2):

The module you're importing depends on another module. Do `pip install scipy`. If you don't have pip, you can read about it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: where to type the command pip install scipy ?]

Comment: do you have pip installed? are you familiar at all with pip? if not you can download get-pip.py and then from the terminal run `python get-pip.py` and then `pip install scipy`

Answer (score 2):

Installing scipy is probably most easily done from within PyCharm. The full instructions are in the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html), but in summary:

1. Go to setting (open from the file menu) and go to the  Project Interpreter page.
2. Click the green plus symbol on the right
3. Use the dialogue box that appears to search for "scipy"
4. Click on "Install Package"

Comment: error numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found                                                                                                                      sol Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe'.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call any scipy functions?  The code you gave doesn't seem to have any-and you have not imported the api.  It looks like you're using sci-kit learn, in which case, depending on which distribution platform you used-you may need to pip install it-which is really easy!

Answer (score 1):

On your terminal, try to run `python -m pip list` and check if `scipy` is installed. If isnt, use `python -m pip install scipy`, to install module.

Comment: which terminal? how should i open the terminal ?

Comment: if you're using Windows, open the CMD. Linux, open your terminal, console of something like this. If Mac, same on linux.

Comment: do i have to navigate in python directory ?

Comment: no, if `python` was installed properly, it already is located at your `PATH` variable, so, u can run this command in any location

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip list
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: try to see [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) and after that, run the command.

Comment: I did exactly according to that tutorial  like this                                           https://i.imgur.com/wUTS9Dg.png                                                                        But in my cmd i am getting error                                                                        https://i.imgur.com/rjuiJeB.png