# Installing src package in python

Tags: python, cmd, src

cmd prompt error saying src directory doesn't exist.

[image: cmd prompt error saying src directory doesn't exist]

I was installing src 0.0.6 package through cmd and I got an error I couldn't figure out. Seeking for a help!

Comment: i tried that too but when i put the command as "python setup.py install" it says python is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @MarkMucha I tried the first way but its giving me the same error. I dint understand the second solution u provided. Can u explain me? I dint understand well, what  environment variables are and how the second solution u provided is going to help me. Thank u

Comment: I have tried the second way too but its the same error iam facing.

Answer (score -1):

From the src package directory, run `C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install` or add python to your path environment variable following the steps here: [adding python path on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) and run `python setup.py install`from the src package directory.