# isacalc says No module named 'src'

Tags: python

after installing the isacalc module I wrote the example code given in the read me.
then I get the error:

```
    runfile('C:/Users/Black/Documents/1-Neff Aero/Python 
    Plots/isacalctest.py', wdir='C:/Users/Black/Documents/1-Neff Aero/Python 
    Plots')
    Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Black\Documents\1-Neff Aero\Python Plots\isacalctest.py", 
   line 8, in <module>
   import isacalc as isa

   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\isacalc\__init__.py", 
   line 1, in <module>
   from isacalc.main_executable import calculate_at_h, get_atmosphere

   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\isacalc\main_executable.py", line 1, in <module>
   from src import Atmosphere

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Code I wrote:

```
import isacalc as isa


atmosphere = isa.get_atmosphere()

h = 11000.0

T,P,d,a,mu = isa.calculate_at_h(h,atmosphere)
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919714/installing-src-package-in-python

Comment: What is `src`? Is the Python snippet your included the contents of `isacalctest.py`? What are the contents of `main_executable.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed isacalc in a virtualenv and looked in `<venv>\Lib\site-packages\isacalc`. This is what I found:

[image]

Huh, weird! No `src` directory for it to import `Atmosphere` from.

No worries, just download the `src` directory from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/LukeDeWaal/ISA_Calculator/tree/master/isacalc/src) and put it in the `isacalc` directory.

[image]

Problem fixed!

Comment: Thank you!  I had to move all the files from the GitHub repo to get it to work. But it does work now.  not sure why :  pip install isacalc      didn't install half the files.