# What should a .py file be opened with?

Tags: python, command-line, cmd, toolchain

I have a .py file (make_standalone_toolchain.py) that I must run in cmd as

```
<NDK root dir>/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 21 --stl=libc++ --install-dir /tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

I know the NDK dir and I am on Windows 10. Currently, my .py files open with PyCharm. this is an issue for when I run the command above, it just opens PyCharm instead of running the script and creating a toolchain.

What should my .py file open with so it will run when I use the cmd line above?

Comment: What happens if you `chmod +x` the file and run it as `./___.py`?

Comment: do you have the python exectutable in your PATH, if yes you should be able to run it with `python <path to file>`

Comment: wrong file association, use "repair" in python install

Comment: Where do I repair and what is file association

Comment: it's covered in the duplicate link. Just run installation program again and select "repair"

Comment: how do I put the file executable in my path? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: you don"t need to. Let me edit the duplicate link to show the "repair" screen

Comment: I tried to repair and it is still a none executable file

Comment: how I add python to the PATH?

Comment: ask google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7