# Setup path for python is not working for me

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using window 10.when  i entered `'Python` in command prompt  then it's show  a message.
*'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file*.
after that i setup the path but the problem is not solved ... i don't know what to do next . I have `python-3.6.5_2`. I google it . but i can't find solution . I  don't know  what's wrong . I do my best  but i unable to fix this problem. please help me  to fix this problem ...thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

This PC -> Right click -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Under "User variables for XXX", click "Path", and click "Edit" -> Click "New" -> Type:

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Python-3.6.5_2
```

(or whatever your python directory is called.)

Now restart your terminal and the python command should work. If you want the "pip" command to work too, add a new path with the same directory but with Scripts/ at the end :

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Python-3.6.5_2\Scripts
```

If you want to know how is your Python directory called, press at the same time :

```
WINDOWS KEY and R KEY
```

it should open a window, and type :

```
%appdata%
```

and now you can find your python directory.

For instance, I'm using anaconda, and the path I use is :

```
C:\Users\FP5721\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
```