# Import xlrd not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import, xlrd

I'm trying to read a .xlxs file in Python using `xlrd`, but I keep getting the error `Unable to import xlrd`.

When I try to re-install `xlrd` using:

```
pip install xlrd
```

I keep getting the message

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.0)
```

And my error message after running my code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/YoungFreeesh/Venture Capital Internship/.../.../Read-csv.py", line 2, in <module>
       import xlrd # import the xlrd module
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

Also, not sure if this is relevant but I'm using Visual Studio & Python 3.6.5

I'm not sure why I can't import `xlrd` since I already have it downloaded.

Comment: It likely has to do with your environment. Figure out where the actual python files for xlrd are located on your computer and try the following code at the top of your module: `import os; os.path.extend([r"path/to/xlrd/parent/folder"])`

Comment: Do you mean like this?

      `import os`      
  `os.path.extend([r"/Users/YoungFreeesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"])`
     `import xlrd # import the xlrd module`

Because this still isn't working. The xlrd folder is in site-packages.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but I've only started using python as of yesterday

Comment: Goodness, I remembered the wrong module. It's supposed to be `import sys; sys.path.extend([path])`. Sorry about that.

Comment: That Works! Thanks!

Comment: So just FYI, this means that when you install something with pip it is going to your site-packages (like it's supposed to) but your PATH is not set up to look in those site packages for the things you import. So unless you want to add that text to every file you write, I'd suggest looking into how to permanently add something to your PATH. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7#6318188

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Make sure you're `pip` installing the right version (3.x or 2.x). If you're using Python 3, `pip3 install xlrd` will make sure it is installed and accessible when running Python3 code.