# How do I add Python to path in Windows?

Tags: python

How do I add python to path? Whenever I type '`python`' in cmd, it opens Python in the Microsoft Store even though I have previously installed Python through their website. However, when I type '`py`' in cmd, python starts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Comment: "py" is copied to your windows path, and available without modification. See the link above for the instructions how to change your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Control Panel ->System and Security->System -> Advanced System Settings

This opens a SystemPropertyDialogBox(Advanced) -> Environment Variables -> Add the Python Path in `Path` Environment variable

And then use another Command Prompt.