# How do i import Tkinter/simplegui in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, tkinter

I tried importing the Tkinter module in Visual Studio Code while writing code for UI development. I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

Do I have to do a `pip install` for this module? Also, how do I do that in VSC?

Comment: If you are using `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter` it won't work. The "t" should be in small letters while importing `tkinter`. Like This: `import tkinter as tk`

Answer (score 1):

Which python version are you using?
Tkinter should come with Python. 
You can allways try

```
python -m tkinter
```

That should open an exemplary window ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)). Further you could also just try to `pip install tkinter`

In python modules (packages) are managed with pip. Pip is indepent of your IDE (in your case visual studio) you can call it from the console. See [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

```
pip --version
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

**Edit** 
 I have a guess what the problem is. Your python version is not correctly in your PATH variable. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) . While installing python you  probably unticked the check box to add python to your path. [Here is also a step by step to fix this](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)

Comment: Currently using version 3.7.4

Comment: I am getting this after trying to pip install tkinter :                                                      
PS C:\Users\HP> pip install Tkinter
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install Tkinter
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You need to be careful with the spelling `tkinter` needs to be written completely in small caps

Comment: Since Python Version 3.4 it does come also with pip already installed. Please try the following in command line `python -m pip install tkinter`